# How does the counterfeit machine interact with the double coins spin prize?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

I am considering buying the counterfeit machine in Jetpack Joyride, but I am curious how it interacts with the double coins spin prize.  Does it:

- A. Remove the possibility of winning the double coins prize.
- B. Make the double coins prize have no effect.
- C. Make the double coins prize worth quadruple coins.

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Counterfeit Coin Machine" or, now called the "Coin Doubler" will duplicate all coins earned once you have entered the game over screen. Effectively, it:

- Doubles all coins you have collected in-game,
- Stacks with the "Double Coin Next Run" power-up (effectively making each coin worth 4 times despite only appearing as 2 times while playing)
- Doubles all coins won through final spin (since those coins are added to your coin collection total)
- Does not affect coins purchased through the "Get Coins" part of the store (those using real money).
- Gemtology will apply bonus coins as per normal, effectively making gems worth 10 times, and normal coins 2 times the value (even though it appears as 5 times and 1 time respectively).

To simply sum it up, everything works as per normal (including the shop) except for in the "Game Over" screen where your coins are doubled. Since the shop doesn't end up in the "Game Over" screen, it doesn't get doubled.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the Jetpack Joyride wiki](http://jetpackjoyride.wikia.com/wiki/In-App_Purchases):

> With the Counterfeit Machine, you receive 2x coins in all occasions, even when using the Final Spin Prize Double Coins.

So the double coins spin prize apparently would have no effect. =(

Answer (score 0):

You get X2 of all coins collected in a run. So if you collect 2000 with a double coins final spin win, you will get 4000 at the end of the run.

The only thing it does not apply to is purchased coin packs.

Comment: Okay, so each coin would get quadrupled?  Cool.  I guess I misinterpreted what the Jetpack Joyride wiki said.

Answer (score 0):

I would think it x4s them. And for mega cash, try equipping Gemology and Free Ride. An expensive pair, but well worth the money.